# Phonegap Push Notification Plugin Error

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, plugins

I am trying to create a push notification for my own android application using Phonegap.

Whenever i add in a plugin into my project file, it gives me an error of this which im unclear of. The error is the X beside my src folder. Does anyone out there is having the same error as me?

Currently using this tutorial: https://www.formget.com/phonegap-push-notifications/

[Eclipse Project Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vaih.jpg)

Comment: do you have `android-support-v4.jar` in project

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Hello there! yes i have that in my project and it have significantly reduced my error. however, there is still some errors in it.

Comment: Not a solution to your question, however i myself like to use the phonegap-plugin-push. this works great for me https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push